# Load Lightning Quickaction programatically (without losing Modal)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction

I have a Lightning component which `implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId"`. The UI is content in a modal which is floating on top of a record page.

At a certain point, my component navigates to another Lightning page. I now need a button on this page that can basically go back. But when I do this

```
redo: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
   var event = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
   event.setParams({
        componentDef: "c:configurationWizard",
        componentAttributes: {
            recordId : cmp.get("v.recordId")
        }
    });
    event.fire(); 
},
```

there is no modal anymore. Is there any other way to reload a quickaction so it diplays properly?

Comment: did you try going back? you can try `$A.get("e.force:navigateBack").fire();` or `window.history.back()`